# Why my macro runs slowly but step-by-step is fast?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter data from a table (not pivot table) and then move boxplot charts and scatter charts to different sheets. I tried to do this by looping at the beginning but I don't know how since every "category" is named differently and also I want to copy charts as pictures and name them as I paste them to different sheets. Very rarely my macro runs in 5 minutes but 9/10 times it takes over 60 minutes to complete. But if I run it step-by-step, it works perfectly. Hope someone can help me. Below is part of my code. There are actually 10 categories (below displayed only 2) so it is really long and heavy.

```
Sub CreateCharts()

'CreateCharts Macro


'Speed up the macro

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Application.EnableEvents = False

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


'Filter data

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        "Chart 01"

'CopyPaste boxplot charts

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C1").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet1_C1")

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C2").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B39")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet1_C2")


'Refresh calculation on the data of scatter plots

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Cust").Calculate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Prod").Calculate

'Activate data labels

    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C3").Activate
    ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("C3").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.ShowRange = False
    Selection.ShowRange = True
    Selection.AutoText = True
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False


    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C4").Activate
    ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("C4").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.ShowRange = False
    Selection.ShowRange = True
    Selection.AutoText = True
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False


    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C5").Activate
    ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("C5").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.ShowRange = False
    Selection.ShowRange = True
    Selection.AutoText = True
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False

'CopyPaste scatter charts

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C3").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X2")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet1_C3")

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C4").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X42")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet1_C4")

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C5").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X80")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet1_C5")


'Filter data

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        "Chart 02"

'CopyPaste boxplot charts

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C1").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet2_C1")

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C2").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B39")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet2_C2")


'Refresh calculation on the data of scatter plots

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Cust").Calculate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Prod").Calculate

'Activate data labels

    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C3").Activate
    ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("C3").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.ShowRange = False
    Selection.ShowRange = True
    Selection.AutoText = True
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False


    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C4").Activate
    ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("C4").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.ShowRange = False
    Selection.ShowRange = True
    Selection.AutoText = True
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False


    Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C5").Activate
    ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("C5").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.ShowRange = False
    Selection.ShowRange = True
    Selection.AutoText = True
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False

'CopyPaste scatter charts

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C3").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet2").Range("X2")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet2_C3")

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C4").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet2").Range("X42")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet2_C4")

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("C5").CopyPicture
            Application.Goto Sheets("Sheet2").Range("X80")
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet2_C5")


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

Application.EnableEvents = True

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to get rid of `Application.Goto` and start using the direct references like `Sheet.Paste` etc. Also in the entire code you are using `ActiveChart` and `Activesheet`, `ThisWorkbook` etc, best approach would be to assign a name to the workbook and worksheets in the start of your code and use those throughout. That will definitely make your code work Faster.

Comment: If the code is running then you are doing right, but there are other approaches to do the same thing. So if you want to write a code that is faster and elegant, you need to get rid of the above mentioned lines. They usually slow down the process.

Comment: Just to clearify, am I doing this right?

Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim charts As Worksheet
Set charts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ("Charts")

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ("Sheet1")

'Filter data

wb.ws1.Select
ws1.ListObjects ("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _ "Chart 01"

wb.charts.ChartObjects ("C1").CopyPicture
ws1.Range ("B2")
ws1.Pictures.Paste.Name = ("Sheet1_C1")

I tried this way but I get "Method or data member not found".

Comment: See how Chris has done the declaration in the answer. I think you are using the wrong declaration as in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Two things will help you with optimising your code:

- Get rid of all those `Select`'s/`Activate`'s/`GoTo`'s
- Abstract the common code into `Sub`'s

Once you've done that, it will help a little with the speed, and you will find it easier to debug and further optimise then code

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateCharts()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim loData As ListObject
    Dim wsCharts As Worksheet
    Dim rngDest As Range
    Dim chtCx As ChartObject

    On Error GoTo CleanUp
    'Speed up the macro
    SpeedUp

    ' Get refrences
    Set wsCharts = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts")
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
    Set loData = wsData.ListObjects("Table1")

    'Filter data
    loData.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Chart 01"

    'CopyPaste boxplot charts
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C1"), .Range("B2"), "Sheet1_C1"
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C2"), .Range("B39"), "Sheet1_C2"

        'Refresh calculation on the data of scatter plots
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Cust").Calculate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Prod").Calculate

        'Activate data labels
        FormatSeries wsCharts.ChartObjects("C3")
        FormatSeries wsCharts.ChartObjects("C4")
        FormatSeries wsCharts.ChartObjects("C5")

        'CopyPaste scatter charts
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C3"), .Range("X2"), "Sheet1_C3"
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C4"), .Range("X42"), "Sheet1_C4"
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C5"), .Range("X80"), "Sheet1_C5"
    End With

    'Filter data
    loData.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Chart 02"

    'CopyPaste boxplot charts
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C1"), .Range("B2"), "Sheet2_C1"
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C2"), .Range("B39"), "Sheet2_C2"

        'Refresh calculation on the data of scatter plots
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Cust").Calculate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Prod").Calculate

        'Activate data labels
        FormatSeries wsCharts.ChartObjects("C3")
        FormatSeries wsCharts.ChartObjects("C4")
        FormatSeries wsCharts.ChartObjects("C5")

        'CopyPaste scatter charts
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C3"), .Range("X2"), "Sheet2_C3"
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C4"), .Range("X42"), "Sheet2_C4"
        CopyChart wsCharts.ChartObjects("C5"), .Range("X80"), "Sheet2_C5"
    End With
CleanUp:
    SpeedUp False
End Sub

Private Sub FormatSeries(Cht As ChartObject)
    Cht.Chart.ApplyDataLabels
    With Cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels
        .ShowRange = False
        .ShowRange = True
        .AutoText = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CopyChart(Cht As ChartObject, rngDst As Range, ChtName As String)
    Dim o As Object
    rngDst.Worksheet.Activate
    rngDst.Cells(1, 1).Select
    Cht.CopyPicture
    rngDst.Worksheet.Pictures.Paste.Name = ChtName
End Sub

Sub SpeedUp(Optional TurnOn As Boolean = True)
    Static OldCalc As XlCalculation
    Static OldStatus As Boolean
    Static OldPageBreaks As Boolean
    If TurnOn Then
        OldCalc = Application.Calculation: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        OldStatus = Application.DisplayStatusBar: Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        OldPageBreaks = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks: ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Else
        Application.Calculation = OldCalc
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = OldStatus
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = OldPageBreaks
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! However this didn't do much to the speed, it still takes about one hour for the macro to finish. Also, I don't know why the copied charts don't get pasted to ranges I've declared (B2, B39, X2 etc.). They appear to Q37. Should I somehow clear the clipboard to speed up the macro? Where should I put the code that Ryszard suggested below?

Comment: @filido  on further investigation it seems it seems `.Pictures.Paste`pastes at a location relative to the active cell.  See update to the answer - I really dislike this solution, but I can't see an alternative ATM.  Re speed - I never said this was the whole solution, you will need to analyse where the time is going and optimise from there.  Without your actual workbook I can't really help on that.

Comment: My code is just filtering and copying the charts so it is exactly the same as you've helped me but that x 10 times. I noticed that some "categories" or "chart filters" take 1min to finish and others up to 8-9 mins. So I guess it depends on the amount of data and rows in which I can't affect.

Answer (score -1):

You must learn how to use `With` block to operate on the same element and avoid `Select` and `Activate`. It will make your code much faster and cleaner.

When I troubleshoot speed, I always put this in my code, in the place where I want to start measuring how long my code runs. Can be at the start of the procedure, can be later:

```
Dim tim as double: tim = Timer
```

I use the code below to check in the immediate window's log how long my macro ran (it's measured in seconds). You can put it in multiple lines, to see what fragment of the code is slow. It's much easier to solve a problem when you narrow it down to a few lines.

```
Debug.Print "checkpoint 1 " & Timer - tim
```

You may want to reset variable `tim` after this line, else next checkpoints will show time elapsed from start, instead of since the last checkpoint:

```
tim = Timer
```

Also from time to time I would add this line to clear clipboard that grows from pasting and slows things down:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```